# what replaces `aiplatform.CustomContainerTrainingJobRunOp` in `google-cloud-pipeline-components` V2?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

Apparently this class I've been using heavily is removed in V2 and it is not exactly clear from the docs what it should be replaced with.

"Remove aiplatform.CustomContainerTrainingJobRunOp and aiplatform.CustomPythonPackageTrainingJobRunOp components" -
https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/components/google-cloud/RELEASE.md

Any idea? The same document says "Make GCPC artifacts usable in user-defined KFP SDK Python components (Containerized Python Components recommended)", is this the way to go?

Is there any example or manual about smooth migration from one to another?